# Bottomsheet takes full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, bottom-sheet

I am trying not to have a BottomSheet that populates whole screen but to leave some space above when it expanded. Here is my code which onExpand populates whole screen.

```
bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomLayout);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                switch (newState) {
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED");
                        break;
                    case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
                        Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN");
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                Log.i("BottomSheetCallback", "slideOffset: " + slideOffset);
                boolean drawer = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0;
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawerArrow, "progress", drawer ? 0 : 1).start();
            }
        });


        bottomLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v(TAG, "ONCLickListner");

                if (bottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    Log.v(TAG,"state expand");
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG,"state collapse");
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                }

            }
        });
```

Can you please address my problem and suggest a way of making bottomsheet not to take whole screen but for leaving some space above when expanded.
Thanks

Comment: set peekheight in xml or in java file

Comment: I believe peekHeight works with bottom height of Sheet not with spacing above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple trick has done it. I was not able to prevent bottom sheet from having full screen for now, so i had a view which is transparent of my required size, and by adding it to the bottomSheetLayout resolved my issue

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/spaccer"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:alpha="0.6"/>
```

Comment: This approach has drawbacks. First of all, the stub view is draggable. If you have a list underneath it, you'll not be able to scroll the list. Instead, the bottom sheet will follow your finger, because the stub steals the drag events. If it's acceptable in your case, keep in mind that the stub doesn't expand when you collapse the bottom sheet. This means that some of the free space will not be covered by the stub, so the dragging will not be possible on the distance more the stub height from the visible edge of the sheet.

Comment: You should avoid hard coding height values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use maxHeight property for that purpose

```java
bottomSheetBehavior.setMaxHeight(someValueInPixels)
```